# Form not working on mobile

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

This is my site http://dotmappersdesign.com/vbuycars/ where I am able to submit form on desktop version but not on mobile . "Next" button below form is not clickable on mobile. Kindly help me with this and let me know you need any information from me.

Answer (score 0):

it is not about the button being 'not clickable'.
your button is clickable alright, it does trigger an alert when not all fields are filled.

**the problem is that in mobile layout, the sliding animation does not work.**

you can fix it by changing the animation from `left` to `"margin-left"`

```
$('#stepOne').animate({"margin-left": "-=311"}, 500);
```

Comment: if i change "left" to "margin left" screen is moving but not getting next form on mobile device. Kindly help me with this.

Comment: You need to do the same for next form too